# Why won't zfill work on string objects in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to convert dates passed into this function `YYYY-M?M-D?D` into a tuple of an integer and a list, with separate elements for each section of the date. Because of how I am receiving data and how I want to re-use it, I believe I need to use the `zfill()` on each section of the date to append 0s to maintain `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```py
def parse_date(date: str) -> tuple:
    """
    Converts date-string into a tuple, which contains an integer and a split date

    :param date: A date-string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    split_date = date.split('-')
    regex_arr = [
        r"(\d{4}?)", r"(0[0-9]|1[0-2])", r"(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])"
    ]

    for date_section, regex_section in zip(split_date, regex_arr):
        compiled_regex = re.compile(regex_section)
        is_date = compiled_regex.match(date_section)
        if not is_date:
            if len(split_date[0]) != 4:
                raise SyntaxError(
                    f"Invalid Syntax: The date inputed ({date}) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                )
            split_date.replace(date_section, date_section.zfill(2))
            date_section = date_section.zfill(2)

            is_date = compiled_regex.match(date_section)
            if not is_date:
                raise SyntaxError(
                    f"Invalid Syntax: The date inputed ({date}) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                )
```

For whatever reason, zfill just won't work. I have checked to see if the date sections were strings, and they were. I am completely lost.

Comment: `split_date.replace(date_section, date_section.zfill(2))` looks suspicious to me. Remember that `str.replace` does nothing unless you assign the result to something.

Comment: `split_date` is a `list` object which doesn't have a `replace` method.  Did you mean `split_date[0]`?

Comment: As an aside, you should not be raising syntax errors here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why not?

Comment: Because it's **not** a syntax error, which implies an error in the *python source code*, which is encountered at *compile time* by the parser. A more appropriate exception to raise would be a `ValueError`, or a custom exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to Kevin.

Basically, I needed to enumerate the zip and use the index value to update the list
Here is the code:

```py
for i, (date_section,
            regex_section) in enumerate(zip(split_date, regex_arr)):
        compiled_regex = re.compile(regex_section)
        is_date = compiled_regex.match(date_section)
        if not is_date:
            if len(split_date[0]) != 4:
                raise SyntaxError(
                    f"Invalid Syntax: The date inputed ({date}) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                )

            date_section = date_section.zfill(2)
            split_date[i] = date_section

            is_date = compiled_regex.match(date_section)
            if not is_date:
                raise SyntaxError(
                    f"Invalid Syntax: The date inputed ({date}) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                )
```

Big mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with not reassigning after splitting.

This looks very "big" for datetime validation - the problem is already solved inside `datetime.strptime` [(link)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
def parse_date(date: str) -> tuple:
    from datetime import datetime

    try:
        # ensure it is a valid date, i.e. no "1234-56-78"
        d = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d")

        # ensure leading zeros are present if needed - if not date is shorter 10 char's
        if len(date) < 10:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        raise SyntaxError(f"Invalid Syntax: The date inputed ({date}) should be " \
                           "in YYYY-MM-DD format" )

    # return parts as parsed integers
    return d.year,d.month,d.day
```

Testing:

```
print(parse_date("1234-10-11"))
try:
    parse_date("1234-1-11")
except SyntaxError as s:
    print(s)
try:
    parse_date("1234-22-11")
except SyntaxError as s:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
(1234, 10, 11)
Invalid Syntax: The date inputed (1234-1-11) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format
Invalid Syntax: The date inputed (1234-22-11) should be in YYYY-MM-DD format
```